# excel vba sql select data with long data type

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, vba

I have an excel marco script to generate db data to do comparison, I found that excel cannot display whole Long data type content that return from sql statement (only return few letter).

How can I write the sql so that excel can display all contenet in Long data type?

Thanks!!

Comment: what Office Version do you have?

Comment: office 2010, have tried office 2007, they do the same

Comment: E.g. ["APP_ID" IS NOT NULL] only show APP_ID

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa) at the limitations of Excel

If it is a possability for you, I would try to select your data into several columns

```
Select left(string, Len(string)/2), right(string, Len(string)/2) from table
```

You may take a look at refernce for this [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx)

You may also insert an if clause to only split if its over a specific value (e.g. the Excel cell max)

Comment: But Long data type cannot use string function like substr in sql. Actually my data length in that field is about < 20. E.g. ["APP_ID" IS NOT NULL] only show APP_ID. The problem is that excel cannot show Long properly.